# Columns with data-type prefix cause "Type X is not a defined system type" error

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2014

I'm working with a 3rd party database. Usually queries that I write in LINQPad and later translate to Entity Framework Core (2.1) work without any issues. However, not this time.

When I try to use the column `Status` I'm getting the following `SqlException`:

> ```
> Class         16  byte
> LineNumber    1   int
> Message       "Type Enumeration is not a defined system type."    string
> Number        243 int
> Procedure     ""  string
> Server        "..."   string
> Source        ".Net SqlClient Data Provider"  string
> State         2   byte
> ```

so I opend the SQL Server Management Studio and found that this column (and few others) use *strage* data-types:

[image]

with *strage* I mean they are prefixed like here with `Enumeration` or `CurrencyCode:varchar(3)` etc.

I used EF-Core scaffolding to create the entities and the property is defined as:

```
public short Status { get; set; }
```

which looks fine but the EF-Core engine apparently recognized the `Enumeration` prefix and generated this line in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnType("Enumeration");
```

and I guess this is causing the error.

---

I've never seen this before and I'm wondering why is EF-Core failing to query such columns whereas LINQPand isn't and what are those strange data-types?

Is there any *magic* or *secret* option for EF-Core to fix this issue?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299712/235671) answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why* it's showing up like this is because you're using a User-Defined Data Type. This script reproduces the issue:

```
create type Enumeration from smallint null
go
create table T (
    ID int not null,
    E Enumeration not null
)
```

*How* you've ended up in this situation I couldn't say. Most people I know (I appreciate this is just opinion) shun the User-defined types in SQL Server (other that User-defined *table* types) because they only half work to start with.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g. a useful feature for user-defined table types would be if you could apply specific constraints automatically - a number that can only fall in the range 1-100 say. You cannot do this with the UDT system. You can separately create `RULE`s and bind those to columns but you're now distributing this definition in multiple places *and* rules are deprecated anyway.

Comment: Oh, this would explain a lot. Then I'll have to google for how to make ef-core work with such types... or otherwise I'll probably have fix all occurances of the generated `HasColumnType` myself :-(