# How do I configure other user defined data-type with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2014

I'm using scaffolded entities with Entiy Framework Core 2.1. The 3rd party database uses some unser defined data types ([that I didn't know about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280510/columns-with-data-type-prefix-cause-type-x-is-not-a-defined-system-type-error)) that don't seem to be recognized by EF-Core.

According to [The Fluent API HasColumnType Method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascolumntype-method) and [Reverse Enginer: Support type aliases (user-defined data types)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3843) this should work. However, I'm not sure if only for precofigured/built-in types like `Name` or any types.

The engine generates this

```
entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnType("Enumeration");
```

for `Enumeration:smallint` but translating it to SQL doesn't work well so it throws a `SqlException`

> ```
> Class         16  byte
> LineNumber    1   int
> Message       "Type Enumeration is not a defined system type."    string
> Number        243 int
> Procedure     ""  string
> Server        "..."   string
> Source        ".Net SqlClient Data Provider"  string
> State         2   byte
> ```

Is there a way to define other user defined data types or fix this in any other way?

Comment: You may want to [submit a new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new) about this.

Comment: Also, type aliases (aka domains) are very different from user-defined types (UDTs).

Comment: @bricelam [done](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12633)

Comment: @bricelam I'm pretty sure it's a user defined data-type (is shown as such by SSMS) but you can check this out in the submitted issue. I also created a demo that reproduces it.

Comment: Thanks! We suspect it's a UDT too. Unfortunately, these have limited support on .NET Core...

Comment: @bricelam take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299712/235671). There is a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround.

At the and of the `OnModelCreating` method I'll just remove the generated `ColumnType` annotation:

```
  modelBuilder
    .Entity(typeof(MyEntity))
    .Property(nameof(MyEntity.Status))
    .Metadata
    .RemoveAnnotation("Relational:ColumnType");
```

A small helper function that goes over all entities and removes that annotation automatically from all properties that have it should be enough for now.

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ModelBuilder RemoveAnnotations<TDbContext>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, TDbContext context, string name, IList<string> values) where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        var bindingFlags = 
            BindingFlags.Instance | 
            BindingFlags.Public | 
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

        var entityMethod =
            typeof(ModelBuilder)
                .GetMethods()
                .Single(m =>
                    m.Name == nameof(ModelBuilder.Entity) &&
                    m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 &&
                    m.GetParameters().Length == 0
                )
                .GetGenericMethodDefinition();

        foreach (var contextProperty in typeof(TDbContext).GetProperties(bindingFlags))
        {
            var entity =
                contextProperty
                    .PropertyType
                    .GetGenericArguments()
                    .SingleOrDefault();

            if (entity is null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Only the generic overload returns properties. The non-generic one didn't work.
            var generitcEntityMethod = entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entity);

            foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties(bindingFlags))
            {
                var entityTypeBuilder = (EntityTypeBuilder)generitcEntityMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, null);

                if (entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.FindProperty(property) is null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var annotation = 
                    entityTypeBuilder
                        .Property(property.Name)
                        .Metadata
                        .FindAnnotation(name);

                if (values.Contains(annotation?.Value))
                {
                    entityTypeBuilder
                        .Property(property.Name)
                        .Metadata
                        .RemoveAnnotation(name);
                }
            }
        }
        return modelBuilder;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
modelBuilder.RemoveAnnotations(this, "Relational:ColumnType", new[] { "Enumeration" });
```